# How to integrate Jacoco report in Sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm using Jenkins+Jacoco+Sonarqube to test my code. In Jenkins, my mvn command is:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar.
```

After code build in Jenkins, I am able to see the code coverage in Jenkins.
But I cannot get proper coverage percentage in SonarQube.

Comment: This question is duplicated. This could be helpful, visit <https://stackoverflow.com/a/51873499/10224348>

Comment: Thanks Busqaro. I have implemented the same . But I am getting different code coverage in Jenkins & SonarQube. Do you have  any idea why I am getting different result ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a source path issue, maybe you don’t analyze the same sources. Do you have any excluded source files in Jacoco and Jenkins that you didn’t exclude in SonarQube properties, or vice versa?

Comment: No nothing I have excluded . Jenkins I am getting code coverage 84% but in Sonarqube it is 77%.

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't include the generation of the reports. Try instead:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar
```

Breaking it down:

- `mvn` invoke the build system
- `clean` delete all old build output
- `org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent` turn on test reporting
- `install` build and install the result in the local Maven repository
- `sonar:sonar` run a SonarQube analysis